# lineno with multicols in an enumerate list environment

Tags: enumerate, multicol, lineno

I am using the lineno package but have run into a problem when I created a double column list (enumerate) environment. lineno counts each entry in the list as a line so that in the example below the the 15th line is item 11 in the second column. Is it possible to have lineno count the actual printed lines? in which case the 15th line would then be the one beginning with ``dummy...''

---

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4]{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}

\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}

Some Text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{enumerate}

\item A 

\item B

\item C 

\item D 

\item E

\item F

\item G

\item H

\item I

\item J

\item K

\item L

\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}

Some more text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

\end{linenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Workaround: put `columnbreak\nolinenumbers` where the natural column break occurs. In the above example, that would be: `\item F \columnbreak\nolinenumbers \item G`.

Comment: @jon: I think, you should turn your comment into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As @jon answered, you can use

```
\columnbreak\nolinenumbers
```

as a workaround.  One natural placing is at the end of an `\item`:

```
\item F
\columnbreak\nolinenumbers
\item G
```